# binding data web service public url to dropdown in excelcontentApp

Tags: html, web-services, jquery, office365

Here i have created web service and given public url for getting data from the data.I have written following code in office 365 developer preview(NAPA) default.htm page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title>DemoApplication</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/Office.css" />
<!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.0/hosted/office.js"></script>
<!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
<script src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="GetData()">
    <select id="CbxArea" style="width: 200px">
    <option>Select Area</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btnsubmit"/>        
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

fallowing code is written in app.js file

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {    
};
function GetArea(){
var ddlArea = $("#CbxArea");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.3.252:8081/HaraveerWCF/ExcelDataService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //url:"ExcelDataService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                ddlArea.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].AreaName).html(data.d[i].AreaName));
                }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
}
```

Where i have written wrong.Please help me out.Make sure total code is written in only online office 365 portal account.Not written in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done little bit, we can say `override` to options html. You are placing values and the text of the each options:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
  ddlArea.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].AreaName)
                                       .text(data.d[i].AreaName));
}
```

You can achieve this with `$.each()`:

```
$.each(data.d, function(i, v){
  ddlArea.append("<option></option>").val(v[i].AreaName).text(v[i].AreaName);
});
```

Comment: It is also not working, Here I am using office 365 developer preview.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery 1.4+, you could just do

```
for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
   ddlArea.append($('<option/>', { value : data.d[i].AreaName }).text(data.d[i].AreaName);
}
```

Comment: bipen,I tried like what you said like.But result is none.Meke sure I am developing application in office 365 online environment.So please give suitable reply

Answer (score 0):

You may have run into a JavaScript cross-domain data access issue as you're trying to access a remote address from you Office 365 Preview site. If the return type of the request to the remote address is JSONP, then you may be able to override the cross-domain data access issue.

Check with your browser Developer Tools (invoke it with F12 keyboard shortcut & then look under Network tab) or Firefox Firebug if the remote server URL returns any JSONP data.